# How does completion affect the topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given a set $X$ there are two ways to turn it into a topological space, first, specify the convergence (of nets), second, specify the topology.  The two ways are equivalent.

Let $X=C(0,1)$ equipped with the $L^p$ norm, $p<\infty$.  This specifies a topology on $X$. Obviously, $X$ is closed, because this is so in every topology.  However, $X$ is incomplete.  In fact, the completion of $X$ in $L^p$ norm is the $L^p(0,1)$.

Suppose that we have completed $X$ to $\overline X=L^p$.  How did the act of completion change the topology on $X$?  In the $L^p$ topology, we have a relative topology on $X$.  Is this the same as the topology that we started with?  I think no.  This is because $X$ as a subset of $L^p$ is NOT closed in the relative topology, even though $X$ was closed before the completion.

As such, the act of completion throws away some open sets.  But, which ones?  And what exactly did it do?

Comment: What you want to check is that the natural inclusion map $i: X\to \bar{X}$ is a homeomorphism to its image. This comes from the fact that $i$ preserves distances.

Answer (score 2):

Completion doesn't do anything to the topology. It doesn't matter whether $X$ is closed in the completion or not; the subspace topology is by definition the topology such that a subspace of $X$ is closed iff it's the intersection of $X$ with a closed subspace of $\overline{X}$, and $X$ is the intersection of $X$ with the closed subspace $\overline{X}$.

Comment: Hello.  [0,1) is closed by itself, but NOT closed as a subset of [0,1].  Taking the completion influences the topology by introducing limit points.

Comment: @Zizai: no it doesn't. The subspace topology of $[0, 1)$ as a subspace of $[0, 1]$ is still the usual topology. It doesn't know that there's a new limit point because the new limit point is by definition not in the subspace.